# Laravel Download an Uploaded file

Tags: laravel, download, upload, base64, form-data

I need help!! I'm facing a issue with uploaded files. I don't now how to download them properly...

I have a front end that uploads files using **FormData**. Then, in the controller, I simply save the file (a test.txt for example) using:

```
request()->file('attachment')->store('logs', 'public')
```

It saves an rqervdrertwer.txt where it should, BUT, the content of the file is set to a base64 string.

My problem is when I try to download the file. 
How could I achieve that?
If I write in my controller:

```
$pathToFile = storage_path('app/public/logs/' . basename($log->file));
return response()->download($pathToFile);
```

Then it force the browser downloading the file, exactly as it is stored; I mean, the browser gets an base64 string instead of the original content.

So, how could give a download response with a decoded file? and if it is a .pdf or other format?
Or that is not the way to save the file? maybe Laravel has a better approach instead encoding with base64?

Please, help!
Thx!

**EDIT**

Ok, I checked that my problem only occurs when its a .txt file. If the user uploads a .pdf, a .docx, an image, etc, it works ok. So, i'll block any .txt upload :)

Comment: Tried wrapping $pathToFile in a `base64_decode()` when trying to download the file?

Comment: Thx for comment! yes Itried, but, then, I got an Exception ```is_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given```

Comment: Therefore you need to determine the path.. such as: `public_path(base64_decode($pathToFile));` What does $pathToFile store anyway?

Comment: The $path is ok, it is ```$pathToFile = storage_path('app/public/logs/' . basename($log->file))``` and returns an string like this: ```/home/vagrant/code/ERP/storage/app/public/logs/YJ0f3zwDEudKKQM9ASv9tlMa45tHuDwgeW68TAa7.txt```. where is my file. Thx for the comment again!